# To create and run a C# console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Just picked up and started learning and coding with C#. The online course I am learning from is using Microsoft Visual Studio for C# outputting to a console application.

I have downloaded Visual Studio Community from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ but the C# coding language does not have console application as output. Not sure if I am looking at the correct place/ or have downloaded the correct application to code and run C#.

Do the newest versions of Microsoft Visual Studio have this option available? I havent been able to locate or find it in open/create new C# project. Pardon my silly questions, but any help/helpful links are much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create new project form file or start page and select C# category then click on console application.

see this picture:
[image: see this picture]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this option/project type is still available in VS2017. To get this project type, you need to install correct workload i.e. .Net Desktop Development. Then searching `Console` from New Project window, will give you the project type.

[image]

Comment: Thank you appreciate it. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can see in the picture, if you have not C# Console Application.
Please, download the package  of the section.

Comment: Thank you appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Open the visual studio and Select new project. From new project dialog box Select console application. You can see the process in picture [image: here]

Answer (score -1):

please download visual studio 2019 or use command dotnet new command in cmd

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new

Comment: The question states that Visual Studio has already been downloaded.  As far as using `dotnet new`, _what is the question author supposed to do with that?_  Linking to documentation isn't sufficient; you should describe how it applies to this problem, and how to achieve the goal of creating a project that can be edited in Visual Studio.